# How can I use Clojure's distinct? function on a collection?

Tags: clojure

The Clojure **distinct?** method doesn't take a collection, but rather a list of args

```
(distinct? x)
(distinct? x y)
(distinct? x y & more)
```

So *(distinct? 0 0 0 0)* correctly returns **false**, while *(distinct? [0 0 0 0])* returns true. How can I use **distinct?** on a collection so that passing it a collection [0 0 0 0] would return false since the collection contains duplicates?

I do realize that the function is performing correctly, but I'm looking for a trick to apply it to the contents of a collection instead of a list of args.

As a workaround, I currently have

```
(defn coll-distinct? [coll]
   (= (distinct coll) coll))
```

but I feel like I'm missing a more elegant way reusing **distinct?**

Comment: lol, a trick to 'apply' it to the contents

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to pass arguments as a seq to a function, use `apply`.

```
(apply distinct? [1 2 3 1])
; false
(apply distinct? [1 2 3])
; true
```

Comment: how would this work in the case where the collection is empty?

Comment: @KenLiu there is no 0-arity `distinct?` form, so `(apply distinct? [])` throws a "Wrong number of args (0)" ArityException, same as `(distinct?)`. Compare this with `+`, which does have a 0-arity form: `(+)` and `(apply + [])` both return `0`.